# Desktop overlay issue

Tags: gnome, icons

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and updated the system couple of weeks ago due to the security alert. The update seemed to go alright. However when the system starts up it put a black screen in the middle of the desktop and all the icons are fuzzy. On restarting I noticed that the Icons on the desktop fist appear with the background very briefly as wheel icons and are in order then this black panel appears not only reorders the icons but makes them fuzzy. I have tried looking this up and found a bunch of stuff about black screens when the starts but that is not it. One more clue however was that I hit the Win-Key on keyboard it shows me a narrow black strip which appears to correspond with the black panel that I get at the startup. any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "*due to the security alert?*" What 'security alert'?

Comment: Spectre - I heard about a Spectre three weeks ago and updated.

Comment: [Spectre mitigation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown) began long ago, was already baked into 20.04, and is ongoing. No 'special' update is required. Normal Ubuntu security upgrades (which happen silently in the background) handle it. What *exactly* did you do when you "updated?" If you don't know, review your /var/log/apt logs.

Comment: There have been many reports lately about graphical glitches. Reboot to your previous kernel and see whether the issue persists. If not, then temporarily do not upgrade the kernel.

Comment: sudo apt upgrade
  apt list --upgradable
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
  200  lsb_release -a
  201  lspci
  202  sudo apt-get upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libxatracker2
  203  sudo lshw -c display
  204  sudo apt-get upgrade
  205  sudo apt-get update
  206  sudo apt-get upgrade
  207  sudo apt-get autoremove
  208  sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
  209  $ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
  210  lspci -vnn | grep VGA
  211  nvidia-settings --version
  212  sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
  213  sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: Sorry feel like such a Noob

Comment: Hello in the /var.log/apt logs i wrote "apt-get upgrade". I am trying to find this forums guidelines for how to post. I found the log but am not sure how to post it, seems like a lot of stuff upgraded, and I do not know how to roll it back. thanks